# Insert HTML into all Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue were jQuery is not inserting the specified html element into all instances of #element. However, it is only inserting it into the first element but not the other 3 with that id.

```
var htmlcode = '<div class="block"></div>';

$('#element').html(htmlcode);
```

If I switch it to $('div') it will work but this isn't what I want. I need to have this inserted into all divs with the id of #element. From what I understand from the documentation this should be working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ids must be unique on a page. As they are implemented as a fast-lookup *dictionary* there is only one element stored against each key/id.

jQuery and JavaScript can only see the first one because of this.

Use a class instead.

e.g.

```
$('.element').html(htmlcode);
```